# side-by-side, flexible width divs without wrapping?

Tags: css, html

I'm not really sure how to best explain this. I'm trying to have three div elements positioned side-by-side; the first (left to right) is flexible-width, the second is also flexible width, the third is static width and it floated to the right. The first two are inside a div on the same level as the third; that is to keep to total width of the first two under a max-width. 
[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tRJfX/) of what I'm doing.

My problem is that when the text in the middle div is long, the middle div will drop below the first one, instead of having the text wrap. I can't give the middle one a max-width, because the first div is flexible and could get smaller. Any idea how I can go about fixing this?

I know it can be achieved by using a table, but I'd really prefer not doing so unless it's the only easy solution.

**Edit: I decided to just do fixed width.** The amount of work for required for this just wasn't worth it, especially considering that most of the time, the flexible width would never be used for me anyway.

Answer (score 0):

if you wan a pure css based solution then it might be little difficult and also not much browser compatible. Though you can achieve this by using the css property called `display:table ;` and `display:table-cell;`. Again older browser, maybe IE-9 also won;t be able t render this.

Then you should go for the jQuery solution. You can use the following code-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var w = 400 - $('.inner_container .left_box').width();      
    $('.inner_container .middle')css('width',w);
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `display: table` property and related properties, such as `display: table-cell`, have been supported in IE since version 8 -- as well as all versions of Firefox and Chrome/Safari.

Reference: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-table

I believe it's the way to go in your case.

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="inner_container">
        <div class="left_box">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
        <div class="middle">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right_static">Hi!</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    width: 500px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    overflow: auto;
}

.right_static {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: green;
}    

.inner_container {
    display: table;
    width: 400px;
    overflow: auto;
}

.left_box {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: red;
}

.middle {
    display: table-cell;
    background-color: #9999FF;
}​
```

**DEMO**

http://jsfiddle.net/nd7qj/

By the way, you mentioned in your question that the leftmost div should have flexible width, but in the CSS you provided it had fixed width. So I didn't apply a width to it in my code.